# how to crop string in a div

Tags: jquery, html

I have this structure:

```
<div class="person">
  <a href="#">Title &ndash; Description</a>
</div>
```

I need a solution: cut every text behind the dash (with the dash) in the div with the class "person". how can i solve this with jquery?

thank you

Comment: You want to do that on the server side or client side (Javascripts/css)?

Comment: on the clientside with javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$("div.person a").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().split('–')[0]);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BFBbW/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
$(function(){
    var el = $("div.person a");
    el.text(el.text().split('–')[0].trim());
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bHFUK/

Comment: Just curious, did you test this?

Comment: @j08691 nope :) ...it didn't work, but I was close - changed the dash to an actual dash, not the entity. Now it works - http://jsfiddle.net/bHFUK/